# Chain Completables conditionally

Tags: java, rx-java2

Why RxJava will not execute the third completable (`completable3`) if added after a condition?

I have noticed that this is not the only case where the chain seems to be broken so I would like to know the underlying reason why the following code won't execute as expected.

```
Completable chain = completable1
    .andThen(completable2);

if(condition)
    chain.andThen(completable3);

chain.subscribe();
```

I know I could do something like:

```
completable1
    .andThen(completable2);
    .andThen(Completable.defer(() => {
        if(condition)
            return completable3;
        else 
            return Completable.complete();
    }))
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators in RxJava return a new instance which you should continue composing, therefore, ignoring the returned `Completable` results in a no-op. You did the right thing in your second example. For the first example, you can replace the chain reference with the modulated instance returned by `andThen`:

```
Completable chain = completable1
    .andThen(completable2);

if (condition) {
    chain = chain.andThen(completable3);
}

chain.subscribe();
```

Comment: I feel so bad for not seeing it. Thanks!